# The Chain Rule - finding differentials

Tags: calculus, differential, chain-rule

I have been given:

- $V=f(x,y,z)$, with $x= r\cos\theta$, $y= r\sin\theta$   , and $z=t$.
- And asked, find $dV/dr$, $dV/d\theta$ and $dV/dt$

Would
$$
\frac{dV}{dr} = \frac{dV}{dx} * \frac{dx}{dr} + \frac{dV}{dy} * \frac{dy}{dr}
$$
?
If so, what is $dV/dx$ if I have just been given $V=f(x,y,z)$?

I've obtained:

$$V_{r}=V_{x}\cos(\theta )+V_{y}\sin(\theta )$$

I am unsure how to display my final answer.

Comment: Do you know about partial derivatives?  You really want $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$

Comment: What is the definition of $V$ in terms of x y and z?

Comment: take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Differential_calculus). Also take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472660/change-of-variables-in-a-differential-operator)

Comment: It hasn't been provided, is my most recent edit correct?

Comment: Yes I'm well aware of partial derivatives and I think I've used them correctly in my most recent edit

Comment: I've used partial differentiation correctly and obtained my edit

Answer (score 1):

First: using the same name for different things is a **bad** habit that causes confusion. Use different names for different things. In your case:
$$V(r,\theta,t) = f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,t).$$
Then:
$$
\frac{\partial V}{\partial r} =
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} +
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} +
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial r} = \cdots
$$

Comment: I'm confused as to what V is defined as? What function is it?

Comment: @JonnyWhite13, read again the definition: $V(r,\theta,t) = f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,t)$.