# Different ways of calculating second-order partial derivative give different results?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Let $z=f(x,y)$ where $x=r^2+s^2, y=2rs$, find $\partial^2z/\partial r^2$.

We first find 
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}=2r\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+2s\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$
then
$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial r^2}
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}
\left(2r\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+2s\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)
\\
&=2\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+2r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)+2s\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)
\\
\end{align}
$$
put
$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+ 
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+ 
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}
\end{align}$$
into $\partial^2z/\partial r^2$ we get
$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial r^2}
&=2\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}
 + 4r^2\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial r^2}
 + 8rs \frac{\partial^2x}{\partial x\partial y}+4s^2\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}
\end{align}
$$
which is the correct answer.

However, if I try in this way:
$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial r^2}
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}
\left(2r\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+2s\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)
\\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x} 
\left(2r\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+2s\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)
   \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}
 +\frac{\partial}{\partial y} 
\left(2r\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+2s\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)
   \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}
\\
&=(2r)\left(2r \frac{\partial^2x}{\partial x^2}+2\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}+2s\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x\partial y}+2\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}\right)+(2s)\left(2r\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x \partial y}+2\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}+2s\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}+2\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial s}{\partial y}\right)
\end{align}
$$
It gives a different result
$$4r^2\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}+4\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+8rs\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial y}+\frac{2r}{s}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}+\frac{2s}{r}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$
Am I doing anything wrong in this way?

---

**Additional question**

If$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}=2r\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+2s\frac{\partial z}{\partial y},$$
can$\cfrac{\partial}{\partial r}$written as$$\frac{\partial }{\partial r}=2r\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+2s\frac{\partial }{\partial y}$$
and so $$\begin{align}\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial r^2}
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}
\left(2r\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+2s\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)
\\
&=\left(2r\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+2s\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)\left(2r\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+2s\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right) ?
\end{align}$$

If so, why is that? And how can I proceed $\partial^2z/\partial r^2$ next in this way?

Comment: Related, maybe useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2735523/the-chain-rule-finding-differentials/2735697#2735697.

Answer (score 1):

Following your derivatives within the computation of
\begin{align}\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial r^2}
&=\ldots \\&=(2r)\left(2r \frac{\partial^2x}{\partial x^2}+2\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}+2s\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x\partial y}+2\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}\right)+(2s)\left(2r\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x \partial y}+2\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}+2s\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}+2\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial s}{\partial y}\right)
\end{align}
It seems to me, in the evaluation of the terms in $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ you have incorrectly asumed that
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial s}{\partial  x} &= \frac{1}{\frac{\partial s}{\partial s}}, \\
\frac{\partial r}{\partial  x} &= \frac{1}{\frac{\partial r}{\partial s}}
\end{align}
Which is whay, from
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial  s} = 2s$$
you have coefficients of $\frac{2r}{s}$ in $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$